# How to get improve latency when using HtmlAgilityPack to scan a few web links in real-time?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, html-agility-pack, latency

Here is the method I call every second but when I measure the time it takes to complete it, sometimes it takes less than a second but other times up to 4 minutes.

```
HashSet<int> Handles = new HashSet<int> ( );

void MonitorWebsite ( )
{
    string linkIdPrefix = "thread_title_";
    foreach ( var lnk in this.Links )
    {
        doc = web.Load ( lnk );

        var threadLinks = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants ( "a" )
                                        .Where ( link => link.Id.StartsWith ( linkIdPrefix ) );

        foreach ( var topic in threadLinks )
        {
            string id = topic.Id.Substring ( linkIdPrefix.Length ); // remove "thread_title_"
            string name = topic.InnerHtml; // or link.InnerText

            int handle = Convert.ToInt32 ( id );
            if ( this.Handles.Contains ( handle ) == false && name.IndexOf ( "keyword", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) >= 0 )
            {
                string href = topic.GetAttributeValue ( "href", null );

                this.OpenInBrowser ( href );
                SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer ( Properties.Resources.Success );
                player.Play ( );
            }
            this.Handles.Add ( handle );
        }
    }
}
```

How can I improve it so that it takes less time? Is it out of my control? This is a forum website and if my program finishes late then it opens the link late, like 1-4 minutes after the topic has been opened, which in most cases is too late, as someone else already acted before me.

Also I have 3 links in `this.Links` and for each of them `threadLinks` contain about 40 topics on one page which is what I am reading to see if there is a new topic opened. Not sure if going through these 120 makes a difference.

Would there be a way to maybe only get a fraction of the page?

Comment: Profile - if you find that it network delay - Run in parallel on multiple machine from multiple hosting provides (like Microsoft Azure + Amazon WS), make sure to use multiple proxies/anonymizers...:)

Comment: I don't know how I can do anonymization using HtmlAgilityPack. Also I don't want to spend too many resources on my computer because I am running it on my only PC.